# Smarthome app/action doesnt appear in Google assistant companion app under home control

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

**Problem:**
I ve a problem for long time, where the smarthome app I created with Actions SDK doesnt show up in the Google Assistant app under home control as a test app.
I tried 3 different accounts, looked for being signed in with the same account, started from scratch but nothing helped!
Can you please help to solve this, since it is pretty bad that I cant test the final User oAuth flow from the Google assistant app.
This is BLOCKING me from continuing at all and also make me feel that Google Home is not that production ready.

Iam developing the smarthome app action for a worldwide known opensource project and a lot of users ask for Google Home. I have the implementation almost finished and it stucked at this not showing up in the assistant app. So I cant test and the community cant test either!

This is from my point of view, not good for Google and the launch of Google Home. I had many support tickets open, but still no solution. Hopefully the developers feel responsible and can help.

**Environment:**

- MacBookAir: Mac OS X 10.12.15
- Browser: Chrome, Version 59.0.3071.115 (64Bit)
- Android Smartphone (Starting from Android v6)

**Framework:** Actions SDK (gactions)

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Created a new project under
  https://console.actions.google.com/
- Added Actions SDK to my project and run these commands:
  `./gactions update --action_package action.json --project
  <project-id>`

`./gactions --verbose test --action_package
    action.json --project <project-id>`

- Added all needed App information and the Account Linking information
- Clicked on TEST (next to SUBMIT FOR REVIEW) Button

**Result:**

I cant use the Simulator, cause when I type "Talk to ", I always get this     ErrorMessage: "Sorry, this action is not available in simulation". 
If I open the Google Assistant on an Android device and go to "Home Control" to see my test smarthome app, it doesnt occur in the list with brackets etc. like [test ...]. It is not there at all!

I found other devs having the same problem like me over here:
     https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs/issues/1

**Here you have my command in the terminal to deploy the smarthome app via gactions command:**

```
./gactions --verbose test --action_package action.json --project <project-id>

Checking for updates...

Successfully fetched update metadata

Finished checking for updates -- no updates available

Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...

POST /v2/users/me/previews/<project- id>:updateFromAgentDraft?updateMask=previewActionPackage.actionPackage.actions%2CpreviewActionPackage.actionPackage.conversations%2CpreviewActionPackage.actionPackage.types%2CpreviewActionPackage.startTimestamp%2CpreviewActionPackage.endTimestamp HTTP/1.1

Host: actions.googleapis.com

User-Agent: Gactions-CLI/2.0.7 (darwin; amd64; stable/6f4c996f8ee63dc5760c7728f674abe37bfe5fc4)

Content-Length: 369

Content-Type: application/json

Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"name":"users/me/previews/<project-id>","previewActionPackage":  {"actionPackage":{"actions":[{"deviceControl":{},"fulfillment":{"conversationName":"automation"},"name":"actions.devices"}],"conversations":{"automation":{"name":"automation","url":"https://MY-GOOGLE-CLOUDFUNCTION-URL"}}},"name":"users/me/previews/<project-id>"}}

Reading credentials from: creds.data

Successfully pushed the app for the Assistant for testing

Your app for the Assistant for project <project-id> is now ready for testing on Actions on Google enabled devices or the Actions Web Simulator at https://console.actions.google.com/project/<project-id>/simulator/
```

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with the problem as you are. I have sent email to Smart Home team, but they just explained:

"Smart Home Apps not showing in the list of Apps under the Home Control section on the Google Home App is a known issue and we're currently looking into it. I will reach out to you as soon as I have an update on that."

Unfortunately, I do not receive any feedback so far, even I have opened many support tickets.

By the way, the offcial document has updated twice(July 14,2017 and July 25,2017). But it still now not works, I do not know what does it mean! It is very disappointed.

Comment: No, it  is still a known issue and Google Smart Home team are looking for it.

Answer (score -1):

This bug has recently been fixed, so all users should now be able to see their test devices in the Google Home app.

Comment: Are you sure that you've confirmed testing for this project through the AoG console?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't show up. The bug was fixed several months ago.

Comment: anything you doubt I would be missing.?

Comment: After following gactions update and gactions test , with the query patterns I am able to work with my app in simulator and on my mobile. But in assistant-> home security this app doesn't appear.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you're building a Smart Home app, you should not be able to invoke your app using query patterns.

Comment: Still having similar issue, posted a new question. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592432/share-button-not-found-anymore-in-google-smart-home-action-test-simulator