# Share button not found (anymore) in Google smart home action test simulator

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

We are developing a google smart home action. As per [this](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/testing-submitting#share-action) and [this](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/simulator#share_access_to_your_project) guides we added testers as viewer and shared action and it worked few months ago. Now we don't see this share button in our simulator anymore. Wonder how to share with testers anymore? As guides still wants us to share the project through this button.

Screenshot from [documentations](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/simulator#configure_access_and_sharing): [image]

Screenshot of my simulator:
[image]

We are able to add the tester in IAM project, but tester is unable to see the action like owner does ([test] ABC agent) in google assistant app.

Edit 1:
It doesn't work even sharing an action with owner rights. Second user is unable to see that action in Home Control under google assistant app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per discussion with 'Actions on Google Support Team' they say that "There has been a slight modification on the interface in the simulator page. Unfortunately, the current documentation hasn't been updated yet to reflect this change."

You can still share your Action without the share button. To recap:

1. Go to the Actions console and select your project.
2. In the right navigation menu, select the three dot icon and then Manage User Access.
3. This redirects you to the IAM page for your project.
4. Click ADD to set a team member's access to your project. You must be an owner of the project.
5. Type the member's email address in the Members box. To assign view access, from the Roles menu, select Project and then Viewer. The members you add will be able to see the Action on their console. Please note that the system does not proactively notify the added members.
6. Tester/Viewer will have to login in to console and Enable testing in simulator to see the action in Google Assistant App.

Happy Coding !