# How to give access to a different google user and test my Dialogflow app?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-account

How to let a different google user use my dialogflow app? I tried by adding email id of the user (email added as PROJECT Viewer under IAM in Google Cloud Platform Console).However when I went to test with this user on google assistant and said 'talk to myAppName' google failed to identify that user is trying to access the dialogflow app.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: You've tagged this for the Assistant SDK - is this for an Action for the Assistant? Or is this for a different Dialogflow integration?

Comment: This is for Dialogflow integration with Salesforce. Intents are for performing some basic tasks in Salesforce.

Comment: How do you plan to access it? Through the Assistant? Any other clients?

Comment: The plan is to access it through Assistant i.e. tell something like 'I want to create a lead' and a lead would be created in Salesforce.

Comment: So, I stumbled on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793012/how-to-give-access-to-a-different-google-user-and-test-my-dialogflow-app and I was able to solve my issue following the solution.

Comment: You realize you linked back to this same question. {:

Comment: @Prisoner my bad! here is the correct url - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592432/share-button-not-found-anymore-in-google-smart-home-action-test-simulator.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the answer posted by Sagnik, there is another option.

You can submit your action for [Alpha or Beta testing](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/releases). When you do this you can allow people to test your action by adding their email as a tester. You can then send them a [opt-in](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/releases#opt-in_link) link which they can use to get access to your action. Once they have opted in using their phone
they should be able to use your action on any of their devices.

This approach has the following pro's compared to directly adding users to the project:

- Group tester management
- You won't give users access to your Google Cloud Project.
- No need to first use the simulator before you can properly test the action.
- Alpha/Beta access will remain available as long as the period is active, users that are directly added to the project sometimes lose access to an Action after a couple months. (They have to use the test console again to re-enable).

Comment: Thanks Jordi..I didn't know about this. Should be able to release the action to a set of users(just for testing purpose) without going through Google review.

Comment: To clarify - Alpha testing doesn't require Google review. Beta testing, however, **does** require Google review. (The advantage is that once you have passed Beta review, you don't need to re-review it to make it public.)

Comment: did they cancel alpha testing? I can only see production release, no alpha or beta.

Comment: this is not working for me. I have deployed the action in alpha, I have added the email(s), I have shared the opt-in link. when users open the link in Assistant app, an in-app browser appears showing an error page.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the steps as mentioned on [Share button not found (anymore) in Google smart home action test simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592432/share-button-not-found-anymore-in-google-smart-home-action-test-simulator) and was able to put my actions on test to different users!

To recap here are the steps :

1. Open Actions console and select your project.
2. In the right navigation menu, select the three dot icon and then Manage User Access.
   This redirects to the IAM page for your project.
   Click ADD to set a team member's access to your project (added user as viewer).
3. Now switch Google Account to the newly added user and then open Google Actions 
   Console. Now under 'Your Projects' the shared Project should be visible.
4. Now click on the Project and then click on Test tab on the top which enables testing in 
   simulator which basically enables the tester/viewer to see the action on their Google 
   Assistant App.